# Export a docx file directly to MS Word

Tags: blazor, docx, cpu-word

I'm testing Blazor Server to transfer an Access-App with VBA to Blazor Server. The users need to create docx files an pass them directly to MS Word for further editing.

Is is possible in Blazor Server (and WASM) to open code generated docx files directly in MS Word without the need of donwloading them via browser?

All attempts ended in a download via browser. Third party tools (Telerik, Syncfusion, DevExpress etc.) can only edit docx files directly in the Blazor App, but cannot export them to MS Word.

I do not want to create a ui for word processing in the Blazor app, when MS Word is installed and licensed on all client pcs. All users are used to using MS Word on a daily basis to edit Word files.

Comment: Maybe there is a protocol handler registered for office? Then you could maybe use that to interact with office. Not sure if that is a thing though.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to directly open a file in MS Word from a Blazor Server/WebAssembly application without first downloading the file. It's because web browsers have security restrictions to prevent web applications from accessing user's local file system.